# How can I find my Java directory in 10.8.3?

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to run a Lejos application on an NXT. For it to work I need to set up a profile page with the path of Java. I know that Java doesn't come pre-installed on my Mac version, so I downloaded a .dmg to install it. I kept looking for what path the installer used, but I never found it.

I know that java is installed because I ran

```
java -version
```

on terminal, but still can't find the path. Anyone else know how?

Comment: What exactly does the path need to tell Lejos?  Where to find the java compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `which java` will tell you where the `java` binary is within your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

use "which" in terminal when you want to find the directory of a command:

```
which java
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/java
```